Successive Linq Groupjoins not working on DB tables
I'm trying to combine three SQL Server database tables with each other. I've tried it in lambda and non-lambda form, but none of the methods described in many posts here have worked.
I think this lambda is close to working, but I'm not sure what the problem is:
var searchAgents = _db.SearchAgents
                      .GroupJoin(_db.SiteIds, 
                                 searchagents => searchagents.SiteId, 
                                 siteIds => siteIds.Id, 
                                 (sa, si) => new { sa, siteid = si.FirstOrDefault() })
                      .GroupJoin(_db.PlzKoords, 
                                 group => group.sa.Plz, 
                                 plzkoords => plzkoords.Plz, 
                                 (group, plzkoords) => new { group, plzkoord = plzkoords.FirstOrDefault() })
                      .ToList();

It's underlining the second GroupJoin(), saying the type arguments for the method cannot be inferred from the usage
The first GroupJoin() by itself is achieving what it's supposed to when I leave the second one out.

Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically (simplified) C# data models that can be compiled and reproduce the problem with the GroupJoin() calls in your question.  Thanks!

There were 2 issues with my query:

I was trying to connect the first grouped table/object list on a property from the third table/list that wasn't of the same type: plz and plz. (area code). One was string, one was int. It didn't directly show that this was an issue because of joins work in linq.

I needed to call .ToList() after the first .GroupJoin() for linq to be able to combine 2 enumerables instead of an IQueryable and an Enumerable, since the call of .ToList() at the end applies only to the grouping resulting from the second .GroupJoin() at the end. My guess is that .GroupJoin() combines 2 numerous types such as lists and then spits out the same type as a result.


The working query I ended up with goes like this:
var searchagents = _db.SearchAgents
  .GroupJoin(_db.SiteIds,
             searchagents => searchagents.SiteId,
             siteIds => siteIds.Id,
             (sa, si) => new { sa, siteid = si.FirstOrDefault() }).ToList()
  .GroupJoin(_db.PlzKoords,
             group => group.sa.Plz.ToString(),
             plzkoords => plzkoords.Plz,
             (group, plzkoords) => new { group, plzkoord = 
             plzkoords.FirstOrDefault() })
  .ToList();

